# Is there any drawback in altering an existing column datatype from TEXT to VARCHAR(n)?

Tags: mysql

I have an existing column whose data type is `TEXT`. Now I realized that the values are just single strings. So, the data type `VARCHAR(n)` should have been proper in my case. So, I wanted to change the data type from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(n)`.

Now my question is:

I came to know that in case of `TEXT` data type, internally, the data will be stored in another place and a pointer will be saved in the table.
Now if I want to change the data type from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(n)`, will the data be copied into the table?

Basically,I am interested how data migration will take place internally and its possible side effect.

Note: The column is not used as index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name here MAX is the variable name. Say CREATE TABLE foo ( value VARCHAR(20) ); where MAX is 20

Answer (score 1):

The only risk is truncation of data.

Effectively the `ALTER` will

1. Create a new table with `VARCHAR` instead of `TEXT`.
2. Copy all the rows over.
3. Rename to put the new table in place of the original.

So, the question is, will copying a `TEXT` into a `VARCHAR` of the same `CHARACTER SET` do any harm?  The only possible thing is truncation.